# Prove that from $0 > a > b$ follows $0 > b^{-1}>a^{-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, real-numbers

As the  title already suggests, I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> 0 > a > b    follows    0 > $b^{-1}$ > $a^{-1}$

My approach seems to lead me nowhere, as I've ended up (sort of?) **disproving it**:

0 > a | a*1/a = 1 
$ 0 * a^{-1} * a > a $ | /a  
$ 0 *a^{-1} > a/a  $ 
$ \rightarrow  0 > 1$ **Nonsense**

The problem **requires** you to **only** use  the **ordered field axioms**

Comment: $a$ is negative, every time you multiply both sides by it, the inequality is supposed to flip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $0 \gt a \gt b $ both $a $ and $b$ are negative, so their product is positive.

Divide the inequality by $ab$, the inequality sign remains the same. So

$ \dfrac{0}{ab} \gt \dfrac{a}{ab} \gt \dfrac{b}{ab} $

which reduces to

$ 0 \gt b^{-1} \gt a^{-1} $

Comment: brilliant, thank you.